# Moving games from a steam account to another steam account?

Tags: steam

I need help with my steam accounts. I got two steam accounts, and installed games on both. I want to move my games from one account to the other one. The games were bought in a regular store, so I have the CD-codes.

How can I move the games to the other account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retail boxed Steam activated games: can they be resold?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30550/retail-boxed-steam-activated-games-can-they-be-resold)

Answer (score 10):

Once you've consumed the CD key from a retail title by associating it with a Steam account, you can't use it again.

Furthermore, Steam will not allow you to [merge accounts](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1558-QYAX-1965) or move keys between accounts:

> Steam accounts can not be merged together.
>
> Per the Steam Subscriber Agreement, Steam game subscriptions / CD keys are nontransferable and cannot be reset / moved between Steam accounts.

The only exception that I've ever found is Company of Heroes, where I've been able to give away my account keys to other people, even those purchased on Steam.  They limit you to 3 transfers, however.

Comment: A possible workaround to include:  Using Steam's Family settings, you can have the two accounts "share" games between each other.  This would effectively merge the accounts together as you don't need to log-out and back in to access the games on either account.  From there though, it would be best to settle on one account to be the primary.